# How to totally disable e-mail notifications from Twitter?

Tags: twitter, notifications

I have a Twitter account that I use *very occasionally*, hence do not want to receive any e-mail notifications from Twitter. So I went into Settings > Email notifications and disabled them: "Email is disabled." However, I'm still getting notifications:

[image: Notifications example]

Short of deleting my account, does someone know how to tell Twitter to stop bothering me through e-mail notifications?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the platform from which you are trying to stop the notifications to occur is an Android device follow the following steps:

1. Open the app and press on your face:

[image]

2. Then select Settings and privacy:

[image]

3. Then select Notifications

[image]

4. Then select Push notifications

[image]

5. and lastly uncheck the Push notifications slider

[image]

Comment: That's for push notifications on Android, not email.